# adding tesseract library to c++ project in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, tesseract

I'm playing with C++ and tesseract library in mac os. [I installed tesseract library](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#mac-os-x) with `brew install tesseract`.

```
$ tesseract --version
tesseract 3.04.00
 leptonica-1.72
  libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.6.20 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.5
```

I have tesseract installed in following path,

```
$ ll /usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.00/
total 72
-rw-r--r--  1 prayagupd  admin   440 Jul 11  2015 AUTHORS
-rw-r--r--  1 prayagupd  admin  1007 Jul 11  2015 COPYING
-rw-r--r--  1 prayagupd  admin  9773 Jul 11  2015 ChangeLog
-rw-r--r--  1 prayagupd  admin   332 Apr  6 19:44 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-r--r--  1 prayagupd  admin    45 Jul 11  2015 NEWS
-rw-r--r--  1 prayagupd  admin  6326 Apr  6 19:44 README
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  admin   102 Aug 21  2015 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  admin   102 Aug 21  2015 include
drwxr-xr-x  6 prayagupd  admin   204 Aug 21  2015 lib
drwxr-xr-x  4 prayagupd  admin   136 Aug 21  2015 share
```

What I want next is add tesseract lib to a C++ project (which I created with xcode). My assumption was tesseract is available to any c++ project once installed, but I can't see imports in my c++ project. It can't find the file `baseapi.h`.

[image: c++-tesseract]

I am following example from here - [API examples](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample#compiling-c-api-programs-on-linux)

I feel like I still need to tesseract lib to c++ project in xcode, but don't know how.

[image: add tesseract]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking under "$ ll /usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.00/api/" ? At least, it is where I found it on my tesseract folder.

Comment: There's no api package inside `tesseract/3.04.00` for me